# What options are there for high quality transparent file types?

Tags: rendering, file-format

I originally saved as a tiff but I couldn't find an option for transparency. What are the best file types to save as to maintain high quality and have transparency.

Comment: PNG files are very high quality, support an Alpha channel, and do not lose quality after editing (like JPG)

Comment: Thanks NoviceInDisguise! Are they as high quality as a tiff/targa?

Comment: @Animatoring Higher

Comment: Looks like that is the best option then. Thanks! : )

Comment: The file size is also more manageable. The other file types tend to be much larger, and without much benefit. See [**this discussion**](http://www.digitaltutors.com/forum/showthread.php?20996-TGA-v-TIFF-v-PNG) for more details. For in-depth comparisons, go to [**this chart**](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/imageformats.html) which has many formats and specs for them.

Comment: The more concerning issue is that you're having trouble setting up transparency. If you can't do it for TIFF, you'll also have troubles doing it for PNG. Which renderer are you using?

Comment: Go to *Render > Film*  and check *Transparent*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally recommend the .PNG file over TIFF or TGA. Here is why:

**Max Colors:**

- PNG supports 256T (48 bit)
- TIFF supports 16M (24 bit)
- TGA supports 16M (24 bit)

PNG files support more colors per file, resulting in higher quality files.

**Transparency:**

- PNG supports single color/Alpha methods
- TIFF supports none
- TGA supports none

The only major downsize is the resolution cap.

**Max Pixels:**

- PNG 2Gx2G
- TIFF 4Gx4G
- TGA 32Kx32K

If you need more than one quintillion pixels (a 1 with 18 zeros behind it), then the TIFF file might be your best bet, otherwise, go with a PNG file. I also find it easier to work with a PNG file (more programs support it).

For more information visit [**this chart**](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/imageformats.html), [**this discussion**](http://simplymaya.com/forum/showthread.php?t=11329) and also [**this discussion.**](http://www.digitaltutors.com/forum/showthread.php?20996-TGA-v-TIFF-v-PNG)

Another viable high-quality file type would be the openEXR type, a good solution for production.

---

**Important:** Also make sure you have transparency enabled in your render settings as well, as no file type will export from Blender with a transparent value unless it is enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

PNG TGA TIFF openEXR and JPEG 2000 are the image formats that blender can render to that support transparency.

Here they all are in order from best to worst.

**[PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)**

- Universal support
- 4 channels
- Only sRGB color space
- 8 or 16 bits per channel
- small file size, with little compression to image quality.

**[openEXR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR)**

- Good support among 3D, image editors, compositors, and editor programs.
- Multi channeled, can store an unlimited number of channels.
- Any color space
- up to 32 bits per channel
- Large file size, variable amount of compression.

**[TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format)**

- Very good support among 3D, image editors, compositors, and editor programs.
- Multi channeled, can store an unlimited number of channels.
- Many color spaces Grayscale, RGB, CMYK, CIE L*a*b*, YCbCr
- up to 16 bits per channel
- Variable file size, variable amount of compression.
- Older, openEXR has become the mainstream replacement of TIFF.

**[TGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA)**

- Very good support (because it is old)
- 4 channels
- sRGB
- only 8 bits per channel
- Large file size, variable amount of compression.
- Older, openEXR has become the mainstream replacement of TGA.

**[JPEG 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000)**

- Very good support
- 4 channels
- sRGB
- up to 32 bits per channel
- very small file size, however with compression to image quality.