# Take white background out of image with cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image

How can you take the white background out an image texture in the cycles node editor?

Here's the image I found on the internet:

[image: the image I'm using]

What I want to do is add scratches but have a different colour/texture underneath the scratches. Here's my current node setup:

[image: nodes]

Comment: Could you upload an example of the image in question? I assume there is no alpha channel?

Comment: @gandalf3 editing the question so it has the image

Comment: Thanks :) Btw, how do you plan to use the image? (In what way does the background need to be removed?) Perhaps a screenshot of your setup so far would be helpful..

Comment: @gandalf3 added some more infomation

Comment: To do that, all you need is to plug the texture into the mix factor

Comment: @gandalf3 thanks! Did not realize it was that simple!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that, you can use the grayscale map as the [*mix factor*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10595/599).

To mix colors:

[image]

Or shaders:

[image]

The color ramp node is only there to get rid of [jpg compression artifacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27517/599).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Color **MixRGB** node in **Multiply** mode, the white information of your image will be ignored:

[image]